# Annual salary Between 2000 and 6000 to display

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
SELECT EmployeeID, sum( Salary *12 ) AS Annual_Salary
FROM Employee
GROUP BY Salary
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

It displays annual salary but I want to **display annual salary between 2000 and 6000 within** so 
thanks to advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT EmployeeID, sum( Salary *12 ) AS Annual_Salary 
FROM Employee 
GROUP BY Salary
HAVING sum( Salary *12 ) BETWEEN 2000 AND 6000
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT EmployeeID, sum( Salary *12 ) AS Annual_Salary
FROM Employee HAVING Annual_Salary BETWEEN 2000 AND 6000
GROUP BY Salary
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: HAVING really really should go after GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT temp.* FROM 
   (SELECT EmployeeID, sum( Salary *12 ) AS Annual_Salary 
   FROM Employee GROUP BY  Salary) as temp 
 WHERE temp.Anuual_salary > 2000 AND temp.Anuual_salary < 6000
```